# Laravel Excel upload and validate CSV fails at Validator

Tags: php, laravel

I and trying to upload a CSV file and validate it against data types for each column. I am using [Laravel-Excel 3.1](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html) on `Laravel 5.8`.

I am allowing users to upload CSVs and as such the table is generated dynamically. I build an array for the validator (`$this->validator_array') that looks like this:

```
array:6 [▼
  "*.0" => "date_format:d/m/Y|required"
  "*.1" => "integer"
  "*.2" => "date_format:d/m/Y"
  "*.3" => "string"
  "*.4" => "float|required"
  "*.5" => "string|required"
]
```

Then in my `Import class` importing using collection, I call it like this:

```
/**
 * Import CSV into collection
 *
 * @param Collection $rows
 */
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    // Use Laravel to validate
    Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
        $this->validator_array
    ])->validate();

    foreach ($rows as $rowNum => $row)
    {
        // Only start import at desired row
        if ($rowNum >= $this->start_import_row) {

            // Format insert record
            foreach($row as $colNum => $col) {
                $this->formatted_row[$this->table_headings[$colNum]] = $col;
            }

            // Save record in table
            DB::table($this->table_name)->insert($this->formatted_row);

        }

    }
}
```

But it fails with unrecongnized validation. My message is:

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateNumeric|required does not exist.
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$this->validator_array` is already an array, you are nesting it within another one using `[$this->validator_array]` so just try:

```
Validator::make($rows->toArray(), $this->validator_array)->validate();
```